# Need a code to organize files into folders called the file names

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a code to organise a set of files within a folder by creating folders with the original file names in a different folder

I've written the first set of code that organises the files into folders but would like to exclude .Bat files from the code ( so that the batch file itself isn't organised into folders and stays in the %cd%) I also need to adjust the output to a different location

```
@echo on
setlocal
set "basename=."
for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ('dir /B /A-D ^| sort /R') do (

set "filename=%%a"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


   for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!basename!") do if "!filename:%%c=!" equ "!filename!" (

set "basename=!filename!"
      md "!basename!"
   )

   move "!filename!.%%b" "!basename!"
   for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!basename!") do (
:nextprogram
      endlocal
      set "basename=%%c
   )
)
```

expected results: run this batch file in a folder with files. All files are put into their individual folders with the file name now the parent folder name. Ignore .bat file and move output to a different location.

Comment: 1. `dir /B /A-D ^| sort /R` can be replaced by `dir /B /A-D /O-N`. 2. To get the extension do not use `for /F "delims=."` but use the [`~x` modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) like `%%~xa`. 3. Remove the (unused) label `:nextprogram`. 4. Provide an example of source and target data, and describe what is the problem with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your script and even make it a one liner, for example:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('"Dir /B/A-D 2>NUL|Find /V "%~nx0""')Do @RoboCopy . "%%~nA" "%%A" /Mov>NUL
```

If you wanted to still perform the reverse sorted name order, *which serves no purpose*, then:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('"Dir /B/A-D/O-N 2>NUL|Find /V "%~nx0""')Do @RoboCopy . "%%~nA" "%%A" /Mov>NUL
```

If you're wanting to move the files to another location then something like this should do it:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('"Dir /B/A-D 2>NUL|Find /V "%~nx0""')Do @RoboCopy . "C:\SomeOtherLocation\%%~nA" "%%A" /Mov>NUL
```

And if you wanted to exclude all `.bat` files instead of just the running script:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('"Dir /B/A-D 2>NUL|FindStr /LIE ".bat""')Do @RoboCopy . "%%~nA" "%%A" /Mov>NUL
```

Finally, if you wanted to exclude all batch files, *(`.cmd` and `.bat`)*:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('"Dir /B/A-D 2>NUL|FindStr /VIEC:".bat" /C:".cmd""')Do @RoboCopy . "%%~nA" "%%A" /Mov>NUL
```

Comment: These are good & I'm learning a lot from this!!!
I would like the code to ignore that .bat itself, leave the original files where they were, copy the newly created folders with file names & files inside them into a new location, with a folder called the same as the folder name of the %cd% that the batch was run in - sorry i'm a novice at this but i'm attempting to improve

Comment: Is it also possible to write something to say, once code complete do next: 
I'd like to make a few other directories once the parent is created?
at the moment this stops once the loop is complete

Comment: @MJWP, I have provided an answer which in my opinion, performs the task you explained in your question, if you have another question, please ask a new question and mark your preferred answer to this question as accepted; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude your batchfile, stick it somewhere else. An old practice was to create a directory called C:\Belfry as the obvious place to store bats, and add it to your Path environment variable. You can then run it from any Dos window in any directory on that machine.

To change the destination location, why not change

```
set "basename=!filename!"
```

to

```
set "basename=C:\otherlocation\!filename!"
```

Even if you are not in that directory, or even on another drive letter, you can still create subdirectories and move files with the full path. Just make sure it exists first.
And, if it you want to move to a dynamic location, take an input to your batch file to choose that directory.